# Shortest lambda expression for monoadic function compositions in *apply

Tags: r, lambda

I tend to use `*apply` functions a lot and find it cumbersome when I used composed functions. I've seen `pipeR` and `magrittr`.
Say I want to do (I know it does not make sense)

```
lapply(-3:10, FUN=function(x){return(sum(abs(x)))})
```

What is the shortest way I can define `FUN=function(x){return(sum(abs(x)))}`, for now it seems that `{. %>% abs %>% sum}` is the shortest I found.

Is there a way to do `{ sum(abs(.)) }` or something similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this some kind of code golf challenge?

```
library(functional)
lapply(-3:10, Compose(abs, sum))
```

And of course, defining an operator is simple:

```
`%.%` <- function(x, y) Compose(y, x)
lapply(-3:10, sum %.% abs)
```

In fact, Hadley's [pryr](https://github.com/hadley/pryr/blob/master/R/compose.r) package defines this operator.

Comment: You can say that... but really when using lambda it is always more or less a stoty about hoew many characters you type...

Comment: I believe in writing slightly more verbose code if it reduces the cognitive burden.

Comment: Be aware that your definition of the `%.%` uses an unorthodox order of arguments. It’s generally defined the other way round ((f∘g)(x) = f(g(x))).

Comment: @KonradRudolph It's easily fixed. However, this is too much like piping for my taste and doesn't fit my programming style anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Using the module [klmr/functional/lambda](https://github.com/klmr/functional), you can write

```
lapply(-3 : 10, x -> sum(abs(x))
```

Alternatively, you can write

```
lapply(-3 : 10, sum %.% abs)
```

The latter uses the function composition operator which, again, is defined in the module klmr/functional linked above.

Comment: @statquant Caveat: the first piece of code redefines the `<-` operator so you can no longer use it for assignment. This is certainly drastic (though I use it in everyday code).

Comment: Yeah too dratic for me, do you mind adding the packages above each answer so people know which lib to load for what ?

Comment: @statquant The functions are in modules, not packages (‹modules› is an alternative approach to packages in R, you can use them via https://github.com/klmr/modules). You can also just copy the relevant code though, the definition is very simple. At any rate, the answer includes the link to the relevant module.

Comment: arrr I like the *second* syntax very much but leaving packages for modules is a bit too "cutting egde" for me...

Comment: @statquant Defining an operator is simple.

Comment: @Roland very true I could do that